# WebOrb / Spring integration not working

Tags: apache-flex, weborb

I've tried copying the weborb config files across to an existing Spring app, and for some reason my spring services aren't being exposed to WebOrb.

I don't see the spring services shown in the WebOrb console, and when I hit the server methods, I get instances of the service that aren't spring wired.

Although this app uses spring annotations heavily, I've tried hitting my services declared in the following ways (always trying to hit "servicesFacade" as my destination):

```
@Service
public class ServicesFacade ...

@Service("servicesFacade")
public class ServicesFacade ...

<bean id="servicesFacade" class="com.mangofactory.grapevine.service.ServicesFacade" />
```

I must have missed a config step, but I've compared everything with the example, and can't think what it is.

** Note - I haven't copied any other jars from the web-orb folder (notably, I've exlcuded the spring jars), as I already have a working Spring 3.0 install running on my web app.  Could this be the cause?

Steps taken:

Copied from %WEBORB_INSTALL%:

- /webapp/WEB-INF/classes -> WEB-INF/classes
- /webapp/WEB-INF/flex -> WEB-INF/flex
- /webapp/WEB-INF/lib/weborb.jar & jdom-1.1.jar -> WEB-INF/lib

Updated web.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Grapevine</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>weborb.ORBServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>grapevine</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>weborb</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>weborb.ORBServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rds</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>weborb.rds.handler.FrontEndHttpServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>grapevine</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>weborb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.wo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rds</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rds.wo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I have the following spring-related classes in my lib folder:

```
org.springframework.aop-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.security.config-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-flex-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Marty

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your weborb-config.xml (it is in WEB-INF/classes) contains the following line:

```
&lt;serviceInvoker&gt;weborb.handler.SpringBeanHandler&lt;/serviceInvoker&gt;
```

Mark

Comment: Yes, it does.  (along with `SpringBeanBrowser` and a `serviceInsepctor` of type `SpringBeanHandler`

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in the log/console output when you navigate to the Services tab in the management console?

Comment: Could you try registering the following bean:
<bean name="user.bean.registrator" class="weborb.util.spring.UserBeanRegistrator" />
Restart your java server and see if it makes any difference?